# Background color of <SPAN> not working because of bug in browsers?

Tags: html, css, debugging

## Background

As far as I understand from the internet, SPAN and DIV fulfill pretty much the same basic purpose, namely group a bunch of HTML statements to perform some group actions. SPANs and DIVs should not affect colors.

## Question

Can anyone tell me why background colors don't work when DIVs are replaces by SPANs?

## Symptoms

In the code below I want the text surrounded by the DIV to have a red background color. Unfortunately it has a white background color. However, if I change the SPAN into a DIV (line number 1), then I get the color I asked for.

```html
<span class="benefits" style="background-color: red;">
     <div>2023 Survey of 10 billion Respondents!</div>
</span>
```

You can find a live Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/sol-calian/pen/JjaxrGP).

## What have I tried?

- Inline CSS
- External CSS
- Read about SPANs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)
- Read about DIVs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)
- Read about background-color on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)
- Cross-browser testing on [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/). I tried Windows with several versions of Chrome, several versions of Firefox and Safari
- Tested with Firefox 110.0.1 64-bit on a Linux machine
- Tested with Chromium 110.0.5481.100 on a Linux machine
- Tested with Codepen
- Search Google.

Comment: span is an inline element, make it block and it will work

Comment: div elements are **not allowed** inside span elements

Comment: besides what has been mentioned by Temani Afif, you should not semantically misuse a span and a div in that context. A span is an inline container and a div is a block-level container. Use the correct container in the first place. Semantically a div inside a span is just wrong.

Comment: @tacoshy — It's structure, not semantics. div and span are generic elements which don't have any semantics.

Comment: Should I use DIVs only, or SPANs only, but not mixed together? Is that the issue?

Comment: It depends on what you try to do. Should it be a block then use divs or should it be inline with other text then use a span: However never use a div inside a span. The other way around it would be ok.